# How to get datetime format use in window?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, window

I'm developing a RPA software which includes reading the date value in excel. However, as generally known the excel will auto-format the date based on computer. So using same file, open in my computer it will be `dd/MM/yyyy`, in others maybe `M/d/yyyy`.

So my question, is there a way we can get the datetime format use in that computer? maybe from environment variable or vb script?

Alternative solution:
1 - Change date format in excel to using `.`. Example `dd.MM.yyyy`. Excel will never convert `.`. However this is not practically efficient since user need to change date format everytime before running the bot.

Comment: Dates in excel are not stored as a formatted string, but a numeric value. Use that and you don't have to worry about the format.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the regional formats that you need, you could do something like:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal _
  Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F
Private Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTTIME = &H79

Sub getRegionalSettings()
  Dim strLocale As String, lngRet As Long
  Dim shortDate As String, longDate As String, shortTime As String
  
  strLocale = Space(255) 'variable for short date format
  lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, strLocale, Len(strLocale))
  shortDate = Left(strLocale, lngRet - 1)
  
  strLocale = Space(255) 'variable for long date format
  lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLONGDATE, strLocale, Len(strLocale))
  longDate = Left(strLocale, lngRet - 1)
  
  strLocale = Space(255) 'variable for short time format
  lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLONGDATE, strLocale, Len(strLocale))
  shortTime = Left(strLocale, lngRet - 1)
  
  Debug.Print "shortDate=" & shortDate, "longDate=" & longDate, "shortTime=" & shortTime
End Sub
```

...which will return something like:

```
shortDate=yyyy-MM-dd
longDate=dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
shortTime=dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
```

More info on the [`GetLocaleInfoA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoa) function and it's [constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants).

---

Or, a simpler way to get the *result* of current regional settings is to just use the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function:

```
Sub getDateTimeFormats()
  Debug.Print "Long Date:", Format(Now(), "Long Date")
  Debug.Print "Short Date:", Format(Now(), "Short Date")
  Debug.Print "Long Time:", Format(Now(), "Long Time")
  Debug.Print "Short Time:", Format(Now(), "Short Time")
End Sub
```

...which returns something like:

```
Long Date:    Thursday, January 27, 2022
Short Date:   2022-01-27
Long Time:    1:28:12 AM
Short Time:   01:28
```

Comment: the code is for c#/c++ right? can it use for vbscript?